# Skipping input lines with @, # and &

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a data file where some of the lines start with @, # and &. The file also contains the numerical data column. I want only the numerical data column.

So how to write a Fortran program to get fresh data avoiding the line starting with special characters?

I tried with the code provided in the post. But it is reading only first line of the numerical data not the remaining the lines.

```
@ target g0.s1         
@ type xysize
0.05966 -70.06945   0.07000
0.08949 -70.06946   0.07000
0.11932 -70.06946   0.07000
0.14915 -70.06946   0.07000
0.17898 -70.06946   0.07000
@ autoscale onread none
@ target g0.s2         `
```

the code

```
implicit none

integer, parameter :: iu = 10

real               :: x

integer            :: ierr

open (unit=iu,file="data.txt",action="read")

do

   read (iu,*,iostat=ierr) x

   if (ierr == 0) exit

end do

print*,"x =",x

end program xread_data
```

Comment: Read the line, see if the character is there or not, do what you need. That's all. It is really simple. If you want to get more, you must show your code.

Comment: Looks like even the `[fortran*]` filter is not enough to catch all the mistagged questions. `[*fortran*]` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If the line can contained something else than a number, you cannot read it directly as a number, that simply must fail.

So first you should read the line as a character string.

Then you can look at the first character in that line string and if it is a comment, skip the line. If not, try to read the numbers them from the string as from an internal file.

```
character(1024) :: line

open...

do
  read(iu, '(a)', iostat=ierr) line
  if (ierr/=0) exit

  if (line(1:1)=='@' .or.  line(1:1)=='#' .or. line(1:1)=='&') cycle

  read(line, iostat...) x1, x2, x3

end do

close...
```